# Stay in Germany after masters degree

Tags: germany, resident-permit, study

I am going to obtain masters degree in mathematics in Berlin. The market in this field is extremely competitive, so I think about "Plan B".

1. How long can I stay in Germany after graduation? (I heard that 3 years, is it true?)
2. Can I work in different area?
   I mean not as a mathematician: I can work as programmer in IT or, if I will not be lucky, as unskilled worker, like courier, carrier, porter, waiter, stuart,...
3. Who or what decides what job is appropriate for my degree?
4. If I, for example, find such unskilled/"differentskilled" job during or after graduation, can I stay in Germany?

Answer (score 1):

- You can apply for a residence permit to stay after graduation. You should start with the application process well before you graduate.
- Your university should have a student's council (Allgemeiner Studierendenausschuss, AStA).
  **Talk to them now. They can advise.**
- If you are qualified as a programmer, take that as your "Plan B" and not an unskilled job. Trying to stay without a qualified and well-paid job is much harder.
- For all practical purposes **the employer decides** if you are qualified for a highly skilled job where it comes to the difference between a mathematician and a programmer. If they want to hire you and pay you an appropriate salary, you are qualified.